# Google Analytics API in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to perhaps refer to some library and make it possible to use the code for GA in spreadsheet scripts outside the google drive?

Comment: Basically, you are asking SO to do all your work... Nice try!

Comment: I am asking if its possible to add some library to use my code that works in spreadsheets as I cannot find out how to get the library that would have the same functions as the library used in spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

Probably not 100% accurate, but you can include the Google Analytics tracking image as part of the template with the parameters wanted:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.1.7&utms=1&utmn=1894752493&utmhn=www.mysiteiscool.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1280×1024&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=10.3%20r183&utmdt=Tracking%20QR%20Codes%20with%20Google%20Analytics&utmhid=1681965357&utmr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dtracking%2Bqr%2Bcodes%26ie%3Dutf-8%26oe%3Dutf-8%26aq%3Dt%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial%26client%3Dfirefox-a&utmp=%2Fblog%2F2011%2F08%2F18%2Ftracking-qr-codes-google-anaytics%2F&utmac=UA-296882-1&utmcc=__utma%3D230887938.1463229748.1317737798.1317737798.1317737798.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D230887938.1317737798.1.1.utmcsr%3Dgoogle%7Cutmccn%3D(organic)%7Cutmcmd%3Dorganic%7Cutmctr%3Dtracking%2520qr%2520codes%3B&utmu=DC~
```

Or you can refer to the following article for more information on several parameters:

http://adambuchanan.me/post/20500736298/google-analytics-without-javascript-or-cookies

Comment: alright, thanks. i have invented another way, it's quite obsolete though. the spreadsheet is web-deployable as csv and you can file_get_contents the csv and parse it into arrays.